# Improper multivariable integral calculation

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Given a domain
$$D=\{(x,y)\mid 0≤x≤5,y≤x≤3y\}$$
how can I calculate the integral $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\iint_D \frac y x \, dx\, dy}$$
using a $D_n$  domain series?

I have tried to figure out what was the domain series but it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let
$$ u=x,v=\frac{x}{y}$$
and then
$$ x=u,y=\frac{u}{v}.$$

Comment: I have edited the quastion can you give it another look